# Integrate MyAllocator SDK with zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework, sdk, zend-framework2

I have been looking for the help to configure SDK for my Allocator.
I have already followed the steps given in the documentation.

https://github.com/MyAllocator/myallocator-ota-php

From the above documentation I have installed myAllocator using composer and I can see MyAllocator directory inside vendor.
Moving further I tried to copy the code from MaReceiver.php to my controller but this does not work out.

I have also checked how to configure the facebook sdk but this also does not help me to get a good idea to work out with MyAllocator SDK.

Again now tried to created a separate module in zf2 but I did not get any success.

It would be really helpful if anyone can guide me of give me any reference for SDK configuration in zend framework 2.

Comment: Could you show the code you tried to use when copying from MaReciever in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->isPost()) {
    $data = $request->getPost('id');

    $propertyId = $request->getPost('pand_id');
    $password = $data['pand_password'];        
    $guid = empty($data['guid'])? '' : $data['guid'];
    $verb = empty($data['verb'])? 'SetupProperty' : $data['verb'];
    $booking_id = empty($data['booking_id'])? '' : $data['booking_id'];
    $myallocator_pid = empty($data['pid'])? '' : $data['pid'];

    // Instantiate backend interface that implements MaInboundInterface
    $interface = new MaInboundInterfaceStub();

    $interface->mya_property_id = $myallocator_pid;
    $interface->ota_property_id = $propertyId;
    $interface->verb = $verb;
    $interface->guid = $guid;
    $interface->shared_secret = 'xxxx';
    $interface->ota_regcode = $password;            
    $interface->booking_id = $booking_id;

    $interface->mya_property_id = 'M not in else ';
    $router = new \MyAllocator\phpsdkota\src\Api\Inbound\MaRouter($interface);

    // Process request
    $post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $post_body = json_encode($interface);
    $response = $router->processRequest($post_body);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);exit;
}
```

With the above code am successfully able to call the function and work perfectly fine with the value on interface object

But now the problem is that am not able to get the request parameter from MyAllocator